# How do I get the x-axis lables to be hidden between every 5th tick so the graph looks cleaner in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to format the x-axis where the labels only appear under every 5th bar, to make the graph look cleaner. But what I'm getting seems to be ticks appearing at every 5th bar and thus placing the wrong values under the wrong bars. Is it possible to hide the years between every 5th bar?

**Current Graph:**
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import seaborn as sns

# sets style of plot
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
sns.set(style='dark')
sns.set_context('talk')

year = [1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]

acres = [4156000, 4478188, 3036219, 4078894, 7120768, 4197309, 2652112, 4574389, 4658586, 4231996, 6689081, 3278565, 4278472, 2641166, 1915273, 2879095, 1791327, 5109926, 3152644, 3910913, 2986826, 5260825, 4814206, 2382036, 1323666, 1148409, 2896147, 2719162, 2447296, 5009290, 1827310, 4621621, 2953578, 2069929, 1797574, 4073579, 1840546, 6065998, 2856959, 1329704, 5626093, 7393493, 3570911, 7184712, 3960842, 8097880, 8689389, 9873745, 9328045, 5292468, 5921786, 3422724, 8711367, 9326238, 4319546, 3595613, 10125149, 5509995, 10026086, 8767492, 4664364]

ax = sns.barplot(x='year', y='acres')

plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

myLocator = mticker.IndexLocator(base = 5, offset = 0)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(myLocator)

ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
    mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plt.MaxNLocator()` instead, places the ticks in the order that you needed:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# sets style of plot
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
sns.set(style='dark')
sns.set_context('talk')

year = [1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]

acres = [4156000, 4478188, 3036219, 4078894, 7120768, 4197309, 2652112, 4574389, 4658586, 4231996, 6689081, 3278565, 4278472, 2641166, 1915273, 2879095, 1791327, 5109926, 3152644, 3910913, 2986826, 5260825, 4814206, 2382036, 1323666, 1148409, 2896147, 2719162, 2447296, 5009290, 1827310, 4621621, 2953578, 2069929, 1797574, 4073579, 1840546, 6065998, 2856959, 1329704, 5626093, 7393493, 3570911, 7184712, 3960842, 8097880, 8689389, 9873745, 9328045, 5292468, 5921786, 3422724, 8711367, 9326238, 4319546, 3595613, 10125149, 5509995, 10026086, 8767492, 4664364]

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':year, 'acres':acres}) # did this to put the axis label

ax = sns.barplot(x=df['year'], y=df['acres'])

plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(df['year'].shape[0]/4))

ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
    mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

[image]

Comment: Im not sure this is correct. I'm still getting years under the wrong bars.